# Почему в алгоритмы в качестве второго параметра мы передаем указатель на конец контейнера(end), а не просто количество элементов

Tags: c++, stl

Почему в алгоритмы (напрмер: `for_each()`) в качестве второго параметра мы передаем указатель на конец контейнера(end), а не просто количество элементов?

Comment: И как вы сможете использовать количество элементов в InputIterator? Например, который читает данные даже не из файла - из сети?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Потому что это позволяет в алгоритме использовать только одну сущность - указатель, а не две (указатель и счетчик пройденных элементов).

Обобщенные алгоритмы их STL могут работать с указателями, для которых доступен только инкремент на `1`, так что если передавать указатель и количество элементов, придется отдельно шагать указателем и отдельно обрабатывать счетчик.

Если же передавать `end()` - все становится универсальным. Алгоритм работает и с итераторами, и с указателями, и с итераторами, для которых определен только инкремент (как у `std::list`)

Comment: тут даже больше - в некоторых случаях даже неудобно с количеством - например, если читаем с файла. А итератор просто указывает на конец файла.